# Search some text/word in folder containing bunch of PDF files and get count of PDF contains that text/word - Without opening pdf files

Tags: excel, vba

Aim - I want VBA code that should search specific text/word in content inside bunch of pdf files and give me COUNT of PDF contains that word (without opening pdf files)

Currently I have code found on internet giving me count of PDF files that contains specific text in the > Name of pdf files <

But as mentioned I want to modify below code/give me new code that should give me COUNT of pdf files contains that specific word inside the PDF content

Below is the current code I have

```
Sub PDFCONTENT()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim ExcelFN As String
    Dim NumFiles As Integer
    Dim filename As String
    Dim FinsS As String

    For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlDown).Row
        NumFiles = 0

        Folder = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
        ExcelFN = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value

        filename = Dir(Folder & "*" & ExcelFN & "*")

        Do While filename <> ""
            NumFiles = NumFiles + 1
            filename = Dir()
        Loop

        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) = NumFiles
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need a third party tool or library to open each PDF file and process/analyze it. There are no buit in features in VBA to do that. Therefore this question is a way too broad to be answered.

Comment: But we can search the specific text in folder search box that gives the list of pdf files contents that text...so we can get count of that...is it not possible in VBA ???

Comment: Not without using a third party tool or library.

Comment: Without open the PDF Files you will not be able to count the Words. And how @Pᴇʜ said you will need a third Party tool. You can take a look at this Code for Inspiration: https://software-solutions-online.com/how-to-search-a-pdf-for-a-string-using-vba-for-excel/

Comment: Dear Sir, I dont want to open PDF files that takes too much time as pdf files are big....Code you gave is seaching the word after opening the pdf file that will take too much time....

Comment: @Hemant You cannot analyze and count words without opening the files. **That is impossible.** Every program or library will have to do that to analyze the content of the files.

Comment: Please let me know how to get this by VBA code........>Go to link please....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665689/wait-till-pdf-file-open-and-wait-till-pdf-file-close-without-giving-any-specif

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I dont want to count the number of times that word comes in pdf file...i want number of file count that contains that word.....could you please go on below link there people saying grep function can search word in directory and give count of files    please ref https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6648/number-of-files-containing-a-given-string

Comment: Number of words in the file name or number of words in the files text or number of files that contain the word in their file name or number of files that contain that word in their text? Please be clear which of these 4 options you actually mean. And `grep` is a Linux command line tool and not VBA.

Comment: last one - "number of files that contain that word in their text" but without opening the pdf file :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you will get the content of the PDF files, or any files for that matter, without opening the files.  Also, you will need Adobe Acrobat installed to scan PDF files using VBA.  I don't know how much it costs, but it's not free.  If you want a free option, convert all PDF files into Word files and then do scans on those.

```
Sub ConvertToWord()
   Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
   file = Dir("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\" & "*.pdf") 'pdf path
   Do While (file <> "")
   ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\"
          Documents.Open FileName:=file, ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:= _
        False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:= _
        "", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
        Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\" 'path for saving word
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=Replace(file, ".pdf", ".docx"), FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument _
        , LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, _
        WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
         SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:= _
        False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ActiveDocument.Close
     file = Dir
   Loop
End Sub
```

Then, run this code below, in Excel.

```
Sub OpenAndReadWordDoc()

Rows("2:1000000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select

    ' assumes that the previous procedure has been executed
    Dim oWordApp As Word.Application
    Dim oWordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim blnStart As Boolean
    Dim r As Long
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim strFilePattern As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim iCount As Long
    Dim strSearch As String

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        ' We started Word for this macro
        blnStart = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    r = 1 ' startrow for the copied text from the Word document
    ' Last column
    n = ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

    sFolder = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\"

    '~~> This is the extension you want to go in for
    strFilePattern = "*.doc*"
    '~~> Loop through the folder to get the word files
    strFileName = Dir(sFolder & strFilePattern)
    Do Until strFileName = ""
        sFileName = sFolder & strFileName

        '~~> Open the word doc
        Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(sFileName)
        ' Increase row number
        r = r + 1
        ' Enter file name in column A
        ws.Cells(r, 1).Value = sFileName

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r), Address:=sFileName, _
        SubAddress:="A" & r, TextToDisplay:=sFileName

        ' Loop through the columns
        For c = 2 To n
            If oWordDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:=Trim(ws.Cells(1, c).Value), _
                    MatchWholeWord:=True, MatchCase:=False) Then

                    strSearch = ws.Cells(1, c).Value
                    iCount = 0

                    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
                        .Text = strSearch
                        .Format = False
                        .Wrap = wdFindStop
                        Do While .Execute
                            iCount = iCount + 1
                        Loop
                    End With

            ws.Cells(r, c).Value = iCount
            End If
        Next c
        oWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False

        '~~> Find next file
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

ExitHandler:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' close the Word application
    Set oWordDoc = Nothing
    If blnStart Then
        ' We started Word, so we close it
        oWordApp.Quit
    End If
    Set oWordApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub

Function GetDirectory(path)
   GetDirectory = Left(path, InStrRev(path, "\"))
End Function
```

[image]

Here, the counts are the same because I copied/pasted the same file 4x so I had something to loop over.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts...!!!! Bt i am getting stuck at converting pdf to word in "ChangeFileOpenDirectory" & "Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto".......pleas guide

Comment: Everything worked fine for me.  That's pretty standard VBA.  Are you on a Mac, perhaps?  You may have to modify the code slightly to work on a Mac.  I have never used Mac, so I can't say for sure what you need to do.  Again, the code worked totally fine for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73640337/11668632 - CAN ANYBODY HELP ME WITH THAT HELP PLEASE