# Wait till PDF file Open and Wait till PDF file Close - Without giving any specific time in program to wait

Tags: excel, vba

I have one VBA Code that opens the file copy the data inside it and paste it in excel file and then closes the pdf file....but Many times pdf file couldn't open or close in given specified time in program (i.e Wait Time)

Aim - I want to modify my VBA Code such as macro should wait till pdf file open and till it closes so that no any pdf will skip from opening and no any pdf will remain open on my desktop that is making my Code to misbehave.

Please HELP...

MY CURRENT VBA CODE IS -

```
Sub Shell_Copy_Paste()

On Error Resume Next

   Dim o As Variant

   Dim i As Long

   Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

   For i = 2 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row


   o = Shell(Cells(i, 1), vbNormalFocus)


   Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)) 'Wait for Acrobat to load


   SendKeys "^a"   'Select All

   SendKeys "^c"   'Copy

   SendKeys "%{F4}"    'Close shell application

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))

   Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste

   SendKeys "^v"   'Paste

   Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

   Worksheets("sheet1").Activate


    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear all please help me to get that this is very important for me to kno :(

Comment: This is not possible. VBA has no built in function to do that. You could try to use the acrobat library to control it better. But I think you will need the full Acrobat (not the Reader) for this functionality.